# Putting a block of text between 2 tables

Tags: html, css

I am designing a page, which has 2 left-sided tables (one below another), one more table on the right and block of text in the middle. Here is what I've tried:

CSS:

```
#left {
    float:left;
    padding-right: ;
}

#right {
    float:right;
}

#center {
    margin-left: ;
    margin-right: ;
}

#text {
    width:60%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

    <div id="left">
        <table style="width:; background-color:#>
        ...       
        </table>
        <table style="width:; background-color:#">
        ...
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <table>
        ...
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="center">
        <div id="text">
            <h>My text goes here</h>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

The central part (text) appears in the middle of the page, but it is right UNDER those three tables (left- and right-sided), not between them... How do I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: I see it in the middle, and first and second table overlap: http://jsfiddle.net/72t0mjmf/

Answer (score 0):

why are you using float? put the div#center between div#left and div#right. Give your body a width. Now give div#left, div#right, div#center widht=33.33%, it should work. try it out.

Comment: Didn't work. I deleted floats and gave all divs a 33.33% width. Now everything is under each other "Table1, Table2", then "Mytext", then "Table 3". It isn't because of the width of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
<div style="width: 70%;">
 <div style="float: left; width: 20%;">Table1 and Table 2</div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 60%;">My Text</div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 20%;">Table3</div>
 <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out there is more efficient way by using CSS3 Multi-column layout

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673534(v=vs.85).aspx

Bootstrap has a framework, just apply .col-md-N to your divs 
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/